# How to store array in localStorage Object in html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How to store mycars array in localStorage Object in html5?**

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";

localStorage.mycars=?;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`localStorage` is for `key : value` pairs, so what you'd probably want to do is `JSON.stringify` the array and store the string in the `mycars` key and then you can pull it back out and `JSON.parse` it. For example,

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";

localStorage["mycars"] = JSON.stringify(mycars);

var cars = JSON.parse(localStorage["mycars"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check his Link

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

This is like a crash course for working with local storage also check this article from Mozilla Firefox

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/

here is the official documentation for local storage

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

Just For your problem, you can do it like this

localStorage only supports strings. Use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse().`

```
var mycars = [];
localStorage["mycars"] = JSON.stringify(carnames);
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage["mycars"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**LocalStorage** can store strings and not arrays directly. Use some special symbol like **'~'** to concatenate the elements of array and save it as an array. When retrieving , using **split('~')** to get back the array.

Comment: I'd love to see more on this concept @ParagGangil