# Uncaught TypeError when using .push() (for an object) with LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to push an object into an array which is in localStorage:

```js
localStorage.setItem("usersArray" , [])

var username = prompt("What will your username be?")
var password = prompt("What will your password be?")

  var newUser = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  }


var testAccount = localStorage.getItem("usersArray")

testAccount.push(newUser)
```

For some reason I'm getting this in return:
"Uncaught TypeError: testAccount.push is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick"

What can I change to fix this?

Comment: You can only store string in localStorage. When setting, convert to string. After getting, convert back to array.

Comment: [How to store array in localStorage Object in html5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174525/how-to-store-array-in-localstorage-object-in-html5)

Comment: Refer the following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-to-store-an-array-in-localstorage

Comment: How would I be able to store new objects (without discarding earlier ones) in the array when using: `localStorage.setItem("usersArray", JSON.stringify(testAccount))`